# xpath that exclude some specific elements

Tags: xpath

This is a simple version of the HTML of the page that I want analyse:

```
<table class="class_1">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="class_2">
      <td class="class_3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="class_4">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="class_5">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="class_2">
      <td class="class_3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="class_4">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="class_5"><span class="class_6"></span>square</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="class_2">
      <td class="class_3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="class_4">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="class_5"><span class="class_7"></span>circle</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="class_2">
      <td class="class_3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="class_4">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="class_5"><span class="class_6"></span>triangle</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can find the page at 
https://sabbiobet.netsons.org/test.html

If you try in a google sheets the function:

=IMPORTXML("https://sabbiobet.netsons.org/test.html";"//td[@class='class_5']")

i'll obtain:

- - square
- circle
- triangle

I need to obtain all the `<td>` with `class="class_5"` minus the ones that have `&nbsp;` or `<span class=class_7>`.

In other words I want to obtain only these values:

- Square
- Triangle

can somebody help me?

Comment: The sample HTML and the page in the link you provided have a different structure. The HTML in the link misses the `span`elements as children of the `class` elements, that's why the provided answers don't work on your sample page. Please clarify which one is the correct example HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The following XPath expression

```
//td[@class='class_5' and span and not(span[@class='class_7'])]
```

selects all `td` elements having an attribute `class` with value `class_5`, having a child element `span` and not having a child element `span` where its `class` attribute has the value `class_7`.

Note that you could also use

```
//td[@class='class_5' and span[@class='class_6']]
```

to get the same result in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
//td[@class='class_5'][not(text()=' ')][not(./span[@class='class_7'])]
```

where `[not(text()=' ')]` is not testing for a reqular space but rather for a symbol with Unicode code `U+00A0` that you can input from keyboard in windows using `alt+0160` where numbers are to be input from numpad.