# XPath syntax to make a query that exclude some specific element

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

You can find my test html page at https://sabbiobet.netsons.org/test.html

This is the html markup of the page:

```
<table border="1" class="class_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="class_tr">
            <td class="class_td">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="class_tr">
            <td class="class_td"><span class="class_span_ok"></span>square</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="class_tr">
            <td class="class_td"><span class="class_span_ko"></span>circle</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="class_tr">
            <td class="class_td"><span class="class_span_ok"></span>triangle</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to obtain all the text in `<td>` with `class="class_td"` minus the ones that have text empty or  `&nbsp;` or that have a child `<span>` with `class="class_ko"`.

In other words I want to obtain only these values:

```
Square
Triangle
```

Using the importXML function of google sheets and following the suggestion of another user I've tried:

```
//td[@class='class_td' and span and not(span[@class='class_ko'])]
```

but it works only if i put some text between "span" and "/span"

Without any text I'll obtain only an empty result.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: This is not well-formed XML document, because the `&nbsp;` entity is not defined.
You could use the character literal-entity `&#xA0;` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xpath that exclude some specific elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58874244/xpath-that-exclude-some-specific-elements)

Answer (score 0):

**In case the provided non-well-formed document is corrected** to a well-formed one by replacing the undefined entity `&nbsp;` with the equivalent character entity reference `&#xA0;`:

```
<table border="1" class="class_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="class_tr">
            <td class="class_td">&#xA0;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="class_tr">
            <td class="class_td"><span class="class_span_ok"></span>square</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="class_tr">
            <td class="class_td"><span class="class_span_ko"></span>circle</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="class_tr">
            <td class="class_td"><span class="class_span_ok"></span>triangle</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**then this XPath expression**:

`/*/*/*/td
        [@class='class_td'
        and not(span[@class='class_span_ko'])
        and normalize-space(translate(., '&#xA0;', ''))
        ]/>`

**when evaluated, selects exactly the wanted `td` elements**:

```
<td class="class_td">
   <span class="class_span_ok"/>square</td>
<td class="class_td">
   <span class="class_span_ok"/>triangle</td>
```

---

**XSLT - based verification**

This transformation evaluates the above XPath expression and copies the selected elements to the output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select=
    "/*/*/*/td
        [@class='class_td'
        and not(span[@class='class_span_ko'])
        and normalize-space(translate(., '&#xA0;', ''))
        ]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<td class="class_td">
   <span class="class_span_ok"/>square</td>
<td class="class_td">
   <span class="class_span_ok"/>triangle</td>
```

**Note**:

If only the string values of the wanted elements are needed, then the XPath expression can be:

```
/*/*/*/td
    [@class='class_td'
    and not(span[@class='class_span_ko'])
    and normalize-space(translate(., '&#xA0;', ''))
    ]/text()
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunatly the query 
>>   /*/*/*/td[@class='class_td' and not(span[@class='class_span_ko']) and normalize-space(translate(., '&#xA0;', ''))]/text()   <<
does not work. 
The query that you wrote produce a correct result only if i put some text between <span> and </span>. 
Also use "&nbsp;" or "&#xA0;" in this case in ininfluent on the final result. 
The problem is definitly the span element that in my case is empty.

Comment: @Sabbio The XPath expression in the answer selects exactly the wanted `<td>` elements from your example XML document, where the `<span>` elements **are** empty. Why do you think it doesn't "work"? Maybe you have a buggy XPath processor? If so, you need to stop using that buggy XPath processor and to switch to a better one. Finally, you may not have provided in the question the XML document with which you have problems -- with the one that is provided, the XPath expression selects exactly the elements you want.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your time, it is easy to test exactly what i need and what i use, if you try in a google sheets this function >>> =IMPORTXML("https://sabbiobet.netsons.org/test.html";"/*/*/*/td[@class='class_td' and not(span[@class='class_span_ko']) and normalize-space(translate(., '&#xA0;', ''))]/text()")   <<< you obtain an #ND error, because the result is empty.

Comment: @Sabbio: Sorry, but there is no `IMPORTXML()` standard function in XPath and I don't know what it is supposed to do. You must explain all details in the question if you want to have any realistic chance of anyone understanding what you mean. Also `google sheets` has nothing to do with XPath. Also, what is `#ND` error... It seems you are talking in this comment about something completely different than the problem posted